# Error: "No package 'libgpod-1.0' found" when trying to install gtkpod2.1.4

Tags: software-installation, configure

I am very new to using Ubuntu but I know the basics. I've been having a series of errors while trying to compile [gtkpod2.1.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkpod/files/gtkpod/gtkpod-2.1.4-unstable/20130301/). I've managed to fix most of them so far with a little googling, mostly just needed to install dev packages. AT this point I am well and truly stuck though. 
Every time I run ./configure, I get this output:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.33... 0.50.2 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.14.2
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for GTK... yes
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for GDK... yes
checking for GMODULE... yes
checking for GTHREAD... yes
checking for LIBGPOD... no
configure: error: in `/home/leo/Downloads/gtkpod-2.1.4':
configure: error: *** No package 'libgpod-1.0' found
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Are you running 12.04 or 13.10, could you add the info/tag to your question please?

Comment: Sorry, I am running 13.10 64 bit.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install `libgpod-dev`?

```
sudo apt-get install libgpod-dev
```

According to the `INSTALL` file of the tarball you need to install the following dependencies to build `gtkpod2.1.4`:

> The following packages are required for building gtkpod:
>
> ```
>     autoconf (at least 2.55)
>     flex (or lex)
>     gettext
>     glib
>     gtk+ (gtk2 for the 2.0.x stream / gtk3 for the 2.1.0+ stream)
>     libgpod (at least 0.6.1)
>           libgdl
>           anjuta
>     libid3tag (at least 0.15)
>     libgnome-vfs-2.0 > 2.6 (for iPod autodetection under GNOME)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I do in fact not have this. However, when I try to install it I get the error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgpod-dev : Depends: libimobiledevice-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 
And when I try to install libimobiledevice-dev I receive the error 'code'The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libimobiledevice-dev : Depends: libimobiledevice4 (= 1.1.5-0ubuntu2) but 1.1.6-git20140105 is to be installed. Any ideas?

Comment: Try forcing the installation of the archive version (I think you set up a ppa that installed this 1.1.6 version): `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice4=1.1.5-0ubuntu2`. And try again to install `libgpod-dev`